# How to use SCHTASK /QUERY and place output into text file using VBScript and cmd

Tags: vbscript, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

Here is the code that I have currently:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "SCHTASKS /QUERY > winning.txt"
```

In my head this should work correctly, and it runs without errors, but the text file is not updated.

The text file is already created so I do not have to worry about creating the WScript variable

EDIT:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /c SCHTASKS /QUERY > winning.txt"
```

Thank you David! I was looking at those two lines for hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "cmd /c" to the front of the command

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "cmd /c SCHTASKS /QUERY > winning.txt"
```

Comment: Consider commenting on what has changed in this code vs the original question to make your answer more informative.

Comment: This was answered by another person and then the answer was removed, I edited the original post to hold the answer. I re-posted as an answer to further clarify but I cannot provide a description for why this works.